# Protected в Java при наследовании

Tags: java, ооп

Позволяет ли модификатор `protected` сделать так: объявить `protected static` переменную-член в абстрактном классе, чтобы в каждом его наследнике этот член был бы локальным `static` - то есть при изменение его в потомке, он не изменялся в других потомках.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не позволяет. И вообще, static переменные принадлежат классу и не могут быть унаследованы

Comment: Забавно, но `class AA {
    public static int hello = 5;
}

class BB extends AA { }  BB bb = new BB();
System.out.println(bb.hello);
System.out.println(BB.hello);` выведут ответ 5 ........  https://ideone.com/os1yLV

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но это не наследование как таковое. Статическое поле класса аналогично просто глобальной переменной.

Comment: @Nofate значица баг %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский баг где?

Comment: @Nofate в  ̶с̶у̶щ̶е̶с̶т̶в̶о̶в̶а̶н̶и̶и̶ ̶J̶a̶v̶a̶  коде %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, просто к static-полям можно обращаться и через класс и через экземпляр.

Comment: @Kuznetsov Sergey а для чего, если не секрет, понадобилось иметь в наследниках такую возможность

Comment: @Nofate но там же `BB.hello` - а `BB` - это не экземпляр - раз, наследник - два... так что это скорее баг, чем фича.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в чем баг-то?